# Get full commit history from a remote branch to a local orphan branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I recently wanted to cloned a large repository so, I ended up cloning a single branch.

```
git clone --single-branch dev git@github.com:xyz/abc.git
```

This repo has few other branched namely stage & master.

Now my local clone has only the `dev` branch.

My Question: How do I now checkout to the `stage` branch ?

I have tried clearing an orphan branch `git checkout --orphan stage` , but am not able to get the full commit history from the remote stage branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
git fetch <remote> <remote_branch>:<local_branch>
git checkout <local_branch>
```

Example:

```
git fetch origin stage:stage
git checkout stage
```

This downloads the refs/objects from remote branch `stage` and creates a local branch called `stage` with the complete history.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone --single-branch dev git@github.com:xyz/abc.git` should have exited with an error saying `fatal: repository 'dev' does not exist`. Maybe you missed `-b` or `--branch` before `dev`?

In your case, `git checkout --orphan stage` would create an orphan branch `stage` from the latest commit of `dev`. It's not what you want.

The history of `stage` is not fully fetched yet. To fetch `stage` and create a local `stage`:

```
git fetch origin stage:stage
```

Checkout `stage`:

```
git checkout stage
```

This way, the local `stage` may have no upstream branch. Later you can run `git push origin -u stage:stage`.

If you intend to create a local orphan branch `foo` from `stage`, you can run:

```
git fetch origin stage --depth 1
git checkout --orphan foo FETCH_HEAD
git commit
```

Answer (score 1):

- Fetch 1 or all remote branches into your local machine.
- Switch to desired branch
- Pull the recent changes from remote repository.

  ```
  git fetch --all // All branch fetch

  git fetch <remote> <remote_branch_name> // Single branch fetch

  git checkout <remote_branch_name>

  git pull <remote> <branch_name>
  ```

NOTE: You can see the commit history of any branch without switching to that particular branch using

```
   git log <branch_name>
```